# Регулярное выражение по удалению ссылок в тексте

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, ссылки

Есть такая строка с ссылками

```html
Статья подготовлена журналистом Иваном Ивановый (<a href="https://www.facebook.com/">FaceBook</a>), при поддержке IT-портала (<a href="http://test-site.com">TestSite</a>)
```

Как сделать так, чтоб ссылка на IT-портал `<a href="http://test-site.com">TestSite</a>` оставалась, а все другие ссылки удалялись с помощью регулярного выражения и заменялись на `Ссылки запрещены`?

---

Как пробовал решить задачу

Регулярное выражение `/\s?<a[^>]*?>.*?<\/a>\s?/si` - оно удаляет все **теги** ссылок, и заменяет их на `Ссылки запрещены`:
***Статья подготовлена журналистом Иваном Ивановый (Ссылки запрещены), при поддержке IT-портала (Ссылки запрещены)***

Как сделать регулярное выражение которое будет пропускать определенную ссылку?

Comment: Что такое *"ссылки `отличный` от ссылки на IT-портал"*?

Comment: Это я раз 5 редактировал текст вопроса, и удалил лишнего. Ссылка на портал `http://test-site.com` должна оставаться, все другие (отличные) заменяться на `Ссылки запрещены`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
<a(?:(?!http:\/\/test-site\.com).)+?<\/a>
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5aalp

> Статья подготовлена журналистом Иваном Ивановый (**<a
> href="https://www.facebook.com/" >FaceBook</a>**), при поддержке
> IT-портала (<a href="http://test-site.com" >TestSite</a>)

Comment: Не забываем пояснять минусы

Comment: какие минусы пояснить нужно? Я учусь только, сам мало понимаю

Comment: @StudyingAgain я не вам, а тем, кто ставит минусы ответу. Не понимаю, за что

Comment: согласен, самому интересно, за что мне минусы иногда наставляют в хороших ответах. Я как минимум в двух ответах `-1` исправлял на `0` на ответы которые мне были более понятны, и так же работали как и выбранные автором вопроса как `ответ`

Answer (score 3):

Добился автоматизма данной задачи. Комментарии в коде сделал, может кому пригодиться. За определенные термины с доменами прошу не ругать, Я учусь

Отдельное еще раз спасибо [dIm0n](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/398802/dim0n) за помощь с регулярным выражением

---

Задание:

Тестовый домен: `testing.com`, протокол `http://`

Строка: ***Статья подготовлена журналистом Иваном Ивановый ([FaceBook](https://www.facebook.com/)), при поддержке IT-портала [testing.com](http://testing.com);***

Удалить все ссылки с помощью регулярного выражения и заменялись на `Ссылки запрещены` кроме ссылки на `IT-портал <a href="http://testing.com">testing.com</a>`

---

Решение:

```
<?php 
// Определение имени хоста
$linkCurrentSite = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    
// Определение протокола http:// или https://
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) !== '') $connectionProtocol = 'https:'; $connectionProtocol = 'http:';
    
// Определение верхнего уровня домена с переменной $linkCurrentSite
$topLevelDomain = substr($linkCurrentSite, 0, (strpos($linkCurrentSite, '.') - strlen($linkCurrentSite)));
    
// Определение нижнего уровня домена с переменной $linkCurrentSite
$lowerLevelDomain = substr($linkCurrentSite, strpos($linkCurrentSite, '.'), strlen($linkCurrentSite));
    
// Произвольный текст с ссылкой для удаления и пропуска регулярным выражением
$arbitraryString = 'Статья подготовлена журналистом Иваном Ивановый (<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">FaceBook</a>), при поддержке IT-портала  <a href="' . $connectionProtocol . '//' . $linkCurrentSite . '" target="_blank">' . $linkCurrentSite . '</a>';
    
// Регулярное выражение, которое пропустит ссылку соответствующую ссылке из трех частей $connectionProtocol + $topLevelDomain + $lowerLevelDomain
$regularExpressionLinks = '/<a(?:(?!' . $connectionProtocol . '\/\/' . $topLevelDomain . '\\' . $lowerLevelDomain . ').)+?<\/a>/';
    
// Результат работы регулярного выражения, где ссылки не прошедшие проверку заменяться на 'Ссылки запрещены'
echo preg_replace($regularExpressionLinks, '<u>Ссылки запрещены</u>', $arbitraryString);
?>
```

Результат: ***Статья подготовлена журналистом Иваном Ивановый (Ссылки запрещены), при поддержке IT-портала [testing.com](http://testing.com)***